# Angular 2.0 / NodeJS project size

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have been using angular 1.x for a while now and I am currently checking if it's possible for me to **upgrade to 2.0.** I am having **two concerns**.

1. The web development I am doing is with a specific application server which does not have any NPM integration, no build options to transpile TypeScript and so on. This means I will be forced to use the JavaScript version.
2. I am new to usage of NPM and I followed the basic tutorial of AngularJS 2.0. For this application which only has 50 lines of code the entire project is 50 MB on disk because all of the modules downloaded by NPM which I don't all need. This will be a huge dealbreaker because we have a development / quality / production server. If we have 10 web applications of (today) 500 KB, they will together become 500 MB. Transports to production will take ages.

Is this really how it works or am I missing something?

Comment: I can't imagine all those 50mb of modules are part of the actual application deployment, a large chunk of it will be development modules only.

Comment: @Gimby that is my point. How do I know which ones are needed and which ones aren't. 'NPM install' just downloads all of them

Comment: you don't generally need to know, you use a proper build pipeline so that is handled for you at the same time that such things as babel transpiling, minifying, etc. is done. SO is not for making recommendations, but investigate into a tool like webpack which is a popular middleware that takes over after "npm install" has been done.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the NPM modules run on your system, they wont be part of your web application build

There are many techniques like `Ahead-Of-Time compilation, Tree shaking` to ensure Only code that we need for our application to be part of final build.

Currently "Hello world" app for Angular2 is 49KB and Google is working to bring it down to 10KB.

Look at this blog post for more details

http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/06/26/tree-shaking-angular2-production-build-rollup-javascript/

Comment: After I did the 'npm install', my project folder was 50 MB. How will I know which files are actually  needed and which ones are not. Those are the only ones I am interested in transporting through environments.

Comment: If you are using `angular-cli` run `ng build -prod` then check the contents of `dist` directory, only these files will be finally used in browser. I think after AOT and treeshaking the size will be even less